# Creating database using EFCodeFirst on a web-server host

Tags: database, ef-code-first, webserver

Creating the database using EFCodeFirst on a local system had been done. But, when trying to create the database on web-server host, then it gives the error "Create database Permission denied."

I was not able to find out the actual problem in this.

Everything is working fine, if I create the database using EFcodefirst on any other local system but it doesn't work with the web-server host.

Please help in this !!

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Because your schema on a shared web-server host is not "dbo". So you can't or you have not enough permission to create the database (this is the default behavior of the EF Code first, when it can't find the database which is specified by the connection string).
you have 3 choices (at least):

- ask for the higher permission (which is unluckily)
- create a new empty database first, or ask (the host) to do that and then specify its  details in the connection string.
- or just turn off database migrations and do everything manulally (set `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`).

Comment: As this did get me past the error, it would still be nice to be able to understand why the permissions for, in this case a known IIS APPPOOL user, cannot modify the master DB after having had it's permissions set to do so.